# Getting the "provided" dependencies in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to make use of the `provided` configuration in SBT, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the full `provided` dependency classpath.

For simplicity, let's say I have two projects, **A** and **B** :

- **A** has a few (JAR) dependencies, and exports compiled class files to `path/to/A/target`
- **B** depends on **A** in the `provided` scope (
  `Project("B") dependsOn(A % "provided")`) and exports compiled class files to `path/to/B/target`

In **B**, this returns the provided JARs, but not the provided internal dependencies :

```
providedDependencies <<= (update) map (_.select(Set("provided")))
```

This returns the internal dependencies (`path/to/A/target`) for every configuration, but not specifically for the `provided` scope, and does not output the JAR dependencies :

```
providedDependencies <<= (internalDependencyClasspath) map (_.files)
```

However, the **A** module shows up in the `provided` scope when using `show update` in the **B** project.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this task after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863209/sbt-traverse-project-dependency-graph/8036281#8036281), but it was surprisingly hard to find :

```
def providedInternalDependenciesTask(proj: ProjectRef, struct: Load.BuildStructure) = {
    // "Provided" dependencies of a single ResolvedProject
    def providedDeps(op: ResolvedProject): Seq[ProjectRef] = {
      op.dependencies
        .filter(p => (p.configuration getOrElse "") == "provided")
        .map(_.project)
    }

    // Collect every "provided" dependency in the dependency graph
    def collectDeps(projRef: ProjectRef): Seq[ProjectRef] = {
      val deps = Project.getProject(projRef, struct).toSeq.flatMap(providedDeps)
      deps.flatMap(ref => ref +: collectDeps(ref)).distinct
    }

    // Return the list of "provided" internal dependencies for the ProjectRef
    // in argument.
    collectDeps(proj)
      .flatMap(exportedProducts in (_, Compile) get struct.data)
      .join.map(_.flatten.files)
  }
```

Usage example :

```
val providedInternalDependencies = TaskKey[Seq[java.io.File]]
...
providedInternalDependencies <<= (thisProjectRef, buildStructure) flatMap providedInternalDependenciesTask
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution that [F.X.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821995/f-x) provided but it kept showing me an empty dependencies list (both for provided and otherwise).

I found that you can ask the "update" task to give you the full view and then you can filter based on configuration (such as "provided").

```
val providedDependencies = TaskKey[Seq[java.io.File]]("task-provided-deps","The list of dependencies in the 'provided' scope")
...
providedDependencies <<= (update) map {
    up.select(configurationFilter("provided"))
},
```

I used this list to exclude the provided deps from getting jarred up into my "all in one" sonar plugin.